# How to debug a COM object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, iis

I have an IIS server running with this asp code:

```
<%
 Dim form
 set form = Server.CreateObject("Library.Form")

 form.Load "file.html"

 Dim sStr = form.formhtml

 Response.Write sStr
%>
```

How can I find out what are others functions and properties belong to `form` object? like `Load` and `formhtml`

**Unfortunately I don't have the source code**, so I try to do watch through `attach to process` with VS2015, but I not getting the inside properties and functions.

Comment: Just create a new vb.net solution (windows forms or console), paste that code and execute it (except response.write). If you still can't see properties, add a reference to DLL of Library.Form, VS will list every property.

Comment: Yes it works! thank you @FurkanOmay

Comment: @FurkanOmay please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new VB.NET solution (Windows Forms or Console) and paste that code.

```
Dim form
set form = Server.CreateObject("Library.Form")
form.Load "file.html"
Dim sStr = form.formhtml
```

You should be able to debug it inside of Visual Studio.

Since CreateObject uses late binding, in order to obtain full IntelliSense support I suggest adding a reference to the DLL of Library.Form object. Adding a reference is called early binding, with that you can browse all properties without even executing the code.